# New developer process for Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am working on learning Hybris.  I have successfully install hybris, there are lots and lots of blogs out there that talk about getting the core hybris install with your own custom moduleds to make changes to, such as this one:

http://javainsimpleway.com/hybris-b2b-installation/

In the blog above the gentleman creates a mystore.  The question I have is this:  Once you have this all setup, you have made changes to the mystore modules and you want get those changes onto a new developers machine (or productions machine), who do you do it?

What I have tried, which does not work is this:

1. zipped up the bin/custom/mystore, config/local.properties, and localextensions.xml
2. followed his steps 1 thru 4
3. unzipped the files on the new machine
4. jumped down to step 12 where he does an ant clean all initialize

One difference between his process and mine is that I am adding some addon's.  It is my impression that all those changes happen with custom/mystore, but to be safe between my steps 3 & 4 I have rerun the ant addoninstall for all four addon's.

The process I have documented, SmartEdit was not working and I found SAP's documentation about running **ant npminstall** because Hybris does not include npm-related 3rd party JavaScript libraries.  This are blowing up when I go to run **ant npminstall**.

I really feel like I am trying to recreate the wheel here.  I would imagine what I am trying to do is very common to any Hybris team, but I cannot find documentation on how to do it.  Does anyone know of a blog out there that talks about how to migrate the source from one machine to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there are lots and lots of blogs out there that talk about getting the
>   core hybris install with your own custom moduleds to make changes to

Although they may be helpful, I would suggest you stick to official Hybris documentation (e.g. https://help.sap.com/viewer/4c33bf189ab9409e84e589295c36d96e/1905/en-US/8acc8a5a86691014a20781b3f738213e.html) which is quite rich.

> Once you have this all setup, you have made changes to the mystore
>   modules and you want get those changes onto a new developers machine
>   (or productions machine), who do you do it?

For production deployment, please go through https://wiki.hybris.com/display/hybrisALF/Ant+Production+for+Continuous+Integration

However, for simply copying the things from one machine to another machine, whatever artefacts you have already copied to the target machine (after you have installed Hybris on the target machine), are correct. If you are working in a team, you typically set up an SCM (e.g. git, SVN etc.) code repository and then it becomes easier.

> It is my impression that all those changes happen with custom/mystore

This is a wrong impression. When you run `addon install` it creates/updates the `project.properties` file in the addon; not in your custom/mystore. So, if the addon is part of the code repository (which is typically not the case unless it is a custom addon), anyone pulling your code on their machine will automatically get the addon `project.properties` and therefore they will not require to run `addon install` on their machines; otherwise, they need to run `addon install` on their machines. A workaround is to copy the content of the addon `project.properties` to the `local.properties` (and thus getting the changes to the target machine when the `local.properties` is copied to the target machine).

> This are blowing up when I go to run ant npminstall.

Make sure to run `ant npminstall` as an admin user. Please check https://answers.sap.com/questions/12771768/smart-edit-unable-to-find-local-grunt.html for another option.

Comment: Arvind,  Thank you for all the links, I much prefer official documentation when I can find it.  There is a gap in the documentation between the "Creating a Customized B2B Accelerator with Modulegen" and "Ant Production for Continuous Integration", in the continuous integration link it assumes you already have your custom b2b accelerator committed to a scm system.  Are there any files within the bin/custom which should not be commited to scm?

Comment: Arvind, thank you again.  I do have a question about what you said abut addon install.  In truth,I think I simply used the wrong terms, so let me make sure I understand what you mean by: addon install it creates/updates the project.properties file in your addon.  It is my understanding that 'my addon' is simply part of one of the 'modules' (aka java projects under bin/custom) which can be uninstalled as easily as it was installed.  Thus...  Once installed by the developer, there is no need to do it when deploying else where.  Is that correct?

Comment: That is a wonderful link, one I will save, thank you!  The last line before the table says this about AddOns: "They are a type of extension that allow you to add front-end files such JSP, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files, and images without modifying the storefront front-end files directly."  2 Q's: 1) the 'you' is really the process of running install addon, correcdt? 2) Where are these file being added exactly?  I am assuming somewhere within /bin/custom, is that correct?

Comment: I tried the steps in "Ant Production for Continuous Integration", sort of.  I don't have a SCM yet, so I just copied the file from the bin/custom from one instance to another, then after running the install I copied over the config/local* files.  Thane I ran ant clean all, ant npminstall, ant intialize, and then started hybris.  I was able to get into the hac, but when I tried to hit the storefront I got a "server error".  Am I missing a step?